# New Material Library: Center icon, above the text inside button

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-button

I have this button and I want to center the icon inside it but it should also be above the text.

[image]

The thing is, there is an option to set gravity of icon, Which is `app:iconGravity` but it only has two options and none of them is center.
If there's no text, setting the option to `textStart` moves the icon to the center but I want icon to be center and also above the text.

Here's the current code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/payButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="@string/pay"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_pay_black_24dp"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="32dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: drawableTop instead of icon?

Comment: Doesn't work. And really don't know why

Comment: I've just come across this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Trevor Nope. It's so annoying that they don't provide such small functionality!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that they don't think it's a good idea/design but their designer agreed to add the functionality in a future version.

Here is a request/discussion around this topic on their repo:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/671

Right now, the only possibilities that I've found are to:

- Use android:drawableTop instead of app:icon: which is poorly customizable
- Create you own custom view or layout and include it where you need it

I've just submitted a PR to add this feature, as it seems that they agree it should support `top` gravity.

---

**Update (2021-02-17)**

It should now be available on [Material 1.3.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.3.0) by using one of the following options: `app:iconGravity="top"` or `app:iconGravity="textTop"`

Answer (score -1):

The `MaterialButton` view don't allow to do what you want. You will do it manualy with you own views.

Comment: This only applies for contained buttons. I don't see that the question was about contained buttons.